# onKeyPress event is not handling spaces and/or send a backspace when writing spaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, onkeypress

I'm using expo. The only thing I created was a simple TextInput component to handle user input.
The problem is when I write some text in the input and then I type the space button on the keyboard. The space is written into the input field but the onKeyPress event is not being shouted.
Similarly if I write any text and then type the space button two times, the onKeyPress event is shouted but the keys nativeEvent are 'Backspace' and ' '.

Here is the code is used to test it:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  let textInputChangeHandler = ev => {
    console.log(ev.nativeEvent);
    //socket.type(ev.nativeEvent.key);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput onKeyPress={textInputChangeHandler} style={styles.textInput}/>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  textInput: {
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 200
  }
});
```

Example input:
Write 'Hello' --> then type space two times

Console log output:

```
Object {
  "key": "H",
}
Object {
  "key": "e",
}
Object {
  "key": "l",
}
Object {
  "key": "l",
}
Object {
  "key": "o",
}
Object {
  "key": "Backspace",
}
Object {
  "key": " ",
}
```

Expected output:

```
Object {
  "key": "H",
}
Object {
  "key": "e",
}
Object {
  "key": "l",
}
Object {
  "key": "l",
}
Object {
  "key": "o",
}
Object {
  "key": " ",
}
Object {
  "key": " ",
}
```

If I type a single space, the output is:

```
Object {
  "key": "H",
}
Object {
  "key": "e",
}
Object {
  "key": "l",
}
Object {
  "key": "l",
}
Object {
  "key": "o",
}
```

but what I expect is:

```
Object {
  "key": "H",
}
Object {
  "key": "e",
}
Object {
  "key": "l",
}
Object {
  "key": "l",
}
Object {
  "key": "o",
}    
Object {
  "key": " ",
}
```

I used my Motorola One 5g for testing. I did not do any test on an emulator.

Comment: You can check your code in the following emulator, it's working fine! https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-bardeen-3sv9b?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @farzaneh yes, that is is the behavior I want. I tested it on react and it works perfectly; The problem arises just when test it on an android device.

Comment: You also can use `onChange` event handler which detect keyboard characters in data  property of `nativeEvent` object and recognize the `backspace` as `null`.